# jQuery with images sliding

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have these codes:

Code 1:

```
<DIV id="Container">
<!-- PICTURE 1 BEGIN -->
<DIV class="Container1">
<DIV class="Picture1">
<IMG src="/Folder/1.jpg" vSpace="0" hSpace="0" style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: Auto">
<FONT class="Picture1Text">
<SPAN>
<SPAN class="Picture1Text-Up">Exclusive</SPAN><BR>
<SPAN class="Picture1Text-Down">News</SPAN>
</SPAN>
</FONT>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<!-- PICTURE 1 END -->
<!-- PICTURE 2 BEGIN -->
<DIV class="Container2">
<DIV class="Picture2">
<IMG src="/Folder/2.jpg" vSpace="0" hSpace="0" style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: Auto">
<FONT class="Picture2Text">
<SPAN>
<SPAN class="Picture2Text-Up">Exclusive</SPAN><BR>
<SPAN class="Picture2Text-Down">Pictures</SPAN>
</SPAN>
</FONT>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<!-- PICTURE 2 END -->
</DIV>
```

Code 2:

```
$("#Container > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function()
{
    $("#Container > div:first")
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .next()
    .appendTo("#Container");
}, 3331);
```

How to achieve sliding/cross-fading of these 2 pictures inside the main Container? Or if you have any other autoslide solution I would appreciate.

Comment: unless you really want to reinvent the wheel you could give slick slider a try: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$("#Container > div[class^='Container']:not(:first)").hide();
    var i= 2;
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $("#Container > div[class^='Container']:visible").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#Container > div[class^='Container']:nth-child(" + i +")").fadeIn(1000);
       if(i == $("#Container > div[class^='Container']").length){
         i= 1;
       }else{
         i++;
       } 
    }, 3331);
```

another effect

```
$("#Container > div[class^='Container']:not(:first)").hide();
    var i= 2;
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $("#Container > div[class^='Container']:visible").slideUp(1000);
        $("#Container > div[class^='Container']:nth-child(" + i +")").slideDown(1000);
       if(i == $("#Container > div[class^='Container']").length){
         i= 1;
       }else{
         i++;
       } 
    }, 3331);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9mg4yvsa/)

Comment: These 2 are good, although I wanted something like this: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow or this: http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/ for a full screen width cross-fading or sliding pictures. Since I put an overlay with text on the pictures, the script I gave above stopped working.

Comment: @Dejan you need to set position to Container and your slide divs to get the fading effect .. but with height auto you can't control that .. so set a spacific height for your images .. anyway play with css .. this is a demo for fading http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9mg4yvsa/3/